# org table lisp concat semi-colon issue

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I am not sure how to describe this problem so I am giving some example

### Without Semi-colon

```
| John | Snow | John Snow |
| John | Doe  | John Doe  |
| Mery | Jane | Mery Jane |
#+TBLFM: $3='(concat $1 " " $2)
```

The result is as expected

### With Semi-colon

```
| John | Snow | " $2) |
| John | Doe  | " $2) |
| Mery | Jane | " $2) |
#+TBLFM: $3='(concat $1 ";" $2)
```

What I expected was -

```
| John | Snow | John;Snow |
| John | Doe  | John;Doe  |
| Mery | Jane | Mery;Jane |
#+TBLFM: $3='(concat $1 ";" $2)
```

Can anyone explain this? and also how to solve this problem.

Comment: I can reproduce. This is obviously a bug thus I suggest reporting a bug to the org mode mailing list instead.

Comment: It appears that `org-table-eval-formula` simply searches for the first ";" as a delimiter between formula and format string.

Comment: so there's no workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look beautiful at all, but just for solving the issue...

You can use

```
(string 59)
```

or

```
"\u003B"
```

instead of `";"`. ASCII number 59 (3B in hexadecimal) stands for semicolon. For other special chars like period, single-quote etc., the same method will work as well.

Comment: You can also use `"\u003B"` (which also works inside constants).

Comment: \u003B looks much better! this helped me as well, thanks